# Get the stream data from WEB API response in windows/ console application

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, download, stream

I need to download the file from WEB API to windows application via stream data.

WEB API :

```
public HttpResponseMessage download(string fileid){

var response = new HttpResponseMessage ();    
response.statuscode= HttpStatusCode.Ok;
response.Content =new StreamContent(filestream);// I have a filestream here .
return response;
```

Here content disposition and content type as added after adding the content .
In client side I have try the following.

```
HttpResponseMessage file = httpclinet.GetAsync("url").Result();

Var stream = file.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result();

using (var data = File.create(@"somepath.txt"))
{
    data.seek(0,seekorigin.begin);

    stream.copyto(data);

}
```

But I didn't get the output. What am getting is 
Stream details like version object of `stream.content` ,`statuscode` . Like that file was written.
How can I write the stream data in this file.

Answer (score 0):

what I would suggest to you is using the [async-await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) keywords here, you can change your code like this to get the results:

```
HttpResponseMessage file = await httpclinet.GetAsync("url");
var stream = await file.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()
```

Also you need to add the `async` keyword to your method like this:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> download(string fileid)
```

Comment: I tried what you have told.the same answer was received. I think there is not much difference.

Comment: Is my way of approach is ok ??

Comment: @user9949432 You need to add it here as well: `var stream = await file.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()`

Comment: Yes I have added the await in both places still the file was wrongly written.